# Is this a bug in .Net reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, linq-expressions

**ANSWER is:** No, this is not a bug.
The difference is in the [ReflectedType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.reflectedtype%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

**So the real question here is:** Is there a way of comparing two `PropertyInfo` objects, for the same property, but reflected from different types, so that it returns `true`?

### Original question

This code produces two `PropertyInfo` objects for **the very same property**, by using **two different ways**. It comes that, these property infos **compare differently** somehow. I have lost some time trying to figure out this out.

What am I doing wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

namespace TestReflectionError
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.BufferWidth = 200;
            Console.WindowWidth = 200;

            Expression<Func<object>> expr = () => ((ClassA)null).ValueA;
            PropertyInfo pi1 = (((expr as LambdaExpression)
                .Body as UnaryExpression)
                .Operand as MemberExpression)
                .Member as PropertyInfo;

            PropertyInfo pi2 = typeof(ClassB).GetProperties()
                .Where(x => x.Name == "ValueA").Single();

            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}", pi1, pi1.DeclaringType, pi1.MemberType, pi1.MetadataToken, pi1.Module);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}", pi2, pi2.DeclaringType, pi2.MemberType, pi2.MetadataToken, pi2.Module);

            // these two comparisons FAIL
            Console.WriteLine("pi1 == pi2: {0}", pi1 == pi2);
            Console.WriteLine("pi1.Equals(pi2): {0}", pi1.Equals(pi2));

            // this comparison passes
            Console.WriteLine("pi1.DeclaringType == pi2.DeclaringType: {0}", pi1.DeclaringType == pi2.DeclaringType);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class ClassA
    {
        public int ValueA { get; set; }
    }

    class ClassB : ClassA
    {
    }
}
```

The output here is:

```
Int32 ValueA, TestReflectionError.ClassA, Property, 385875969, TestReflectionError.exe
Int32 ValueA, TestReflectionError.ClassA, Property, 385875969, TestReflectionError.exe
pi1 == pi2: False
pi1.Equals(pi2): False
pi1.DeclaringType == pi2.DeclaringType: True
```

### Culprit: [`PropertyInfo.ReflectedType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.reflectedtype%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I have found a difference between these two objects... it is in the `ReflectedType`. The documentation says this:

> Gets the class object that was used to obtain this member.

Comment: If you just do PropertyInfo pi1 = typeof(ClassA)... You get the same results.  What is interesting is if compare ClassA to ClassA or ClassB to ClassB then all true.  So I have to agree this behavior does not seem correct.

Comment: Should I make a new question about a reliable way of comparing these objects, or should I edit this question's title? Any opinions?

Answer (score 4):

*Never* assume there's a bug in the library unless you actually know what you're doing and you have exhaustively tested the issue.

`PropertyInfo` objects have no notion of equality.  Sure they may represent the same result but **they *do not* overload the `==` operator** so you cannot assume that they *should*.  Since they don't, it's just simply doing a reference comparison and guess what, they are referring to two separate objects and are therefore `!=`.

On the other hand, `Type` objects also do no overload the `==` operator but it seems comparing two instances with the `==` operator will work. Why? Because type instances are actually implemented as singletons and this is an implementation detail. So given two references to the same type, they will compare as expected because you are actually comparing references to the same instance.

Do not expect that *every* object you will ever get when calling framework methods will work the same way. There isn't much in the framework that use singletons. Check all relevant documentation and other sources before doing so.

---

Revisiting this, I've been informed that as of .NET 4, the `Equals()` method and `==` operator has been implemented for the type.  Unfortunately the documentation doesn't explain their behavior much but using tools like .NET Reflector reveals some interesting info.

According to reflector, the implementations of the methods in the mscorlib assembly are as follows:

```
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    return base.Equals(obj);
}

[__DynamicallyInvokable]
public static bool operator ==(PropertyInfo left, PropertyInfo right)
{
    return (object.ReferenceEquals(left, right)
        || ((((left != null) && (right != null)) &&
             (!(left is RuntimePropertyInfo) && !(right is RuntimePropertyInfo)))
        && left.Equals(right)));
}
```

Going up and down the inheritance chain (`RuntimePropertyInfo` -> `PropertyInfo` -> `MemberInfo` -> `Object`), `Equals()` calls the base implementation all the way up to `Object` so it in effect does a object reference equality comparison.

The `==` operator specifically checks to make sure that neither `PropertyInfo` object is a `RuntimePropertyInfo` object.  And as far as I can tell, every `PropertyInfo` object you would get using reflection (in the use-cases shown here) will return a `RuntimePropertyInfo`.

Based on this, it looks like the framework designers *conscientiously* made it so (Runtime) `PropertyInfo` objects non-comparable, even if they represent the same property.  You may only check to see if the properties refer to the same `PropertyInfo` instance.  I can't tell you why they've made this decision (I have my theories), you'd have to hear it from them.

Comment: `PropertyInfo` is not part of the `System.Linq.Expressions`. It is a `System.Reflection` object, just like the `Type` class.

Comment: I have assumed that `PropertyInfo` objects would behave the same as the `Type` objects do. It does not matter how you get a `Type` of a type, they are always the same object. I thought that the same would be true for property infos.

Comment: Ah right, I thought you were comparing `Expression` objects.  Well, the reason why `==` works with `Type` objects is because type objects are implemented as singletons.  So `typeof(string) == typeof(string)` will _always_ be `true` since they are really referring to the same type instance.

Comment: Yes, and as such, the `PropertyInfo`s that exist inside a singleton `Type` are also singles... at least they should be, I think. In fact, if I try to get the same property two times from a `Type` object, it will give me the same instance... so, how did this second instance of the `PropertyInfo` come to life.

Comment: I mean... if all `PropertyInfo`s come from a `Type`, then how was this second instance created? Unless there is another hidden way of getting these objects... and that is why I am saying that this may be a bug.

Comment: But the documentation indicates it does override Equals   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Reflection.PropertyInfo.aspx And if you test ClassA to ClassA then the result is true.

Comment: Very strange... if it overrides `Equals` method, it should at least return `true` even for two different instances of the same property (I expected that, so just my opinion). But as I have tested, it does not. I was unabled to find a reliable way of comparing two `PropertyInfo` objects.

Comment: Thanks @Blam, I didn't think it did.  But either way, it's still not going to work since he's using the `==` operator and that _still_ isn't overloaded.

Comment: It overrides Equals because it has to, the inherited _PropertyInfo COM interface requires it.  But it just calls base.Equals()

Comment: You are right. I have assumed a bug, where there is no bug... what a shame! =\ ... but now, how can I compare these two objects? Even if they are different objects (and there is a reason for it), how can I determine whether they represent the same property?

Comment: -1: The bold+italics is misleading considering `PropertyInfo` **does** override `Equals`. The statement that "`PropertyInfo` objects have no notion of equality" is flat wrong. Also, since .NET 4 `PropertyInfo` also defines the `==` and `!=` operators.

Comment: Another incorrect statement about reference equality being an implementation detail: I can't find it in ECMA-335 (yet), but since (at least) .NET 1.1, `System.Type` has had a note similar to the following: "A Type object that represents a type is unique; that is, two Type object references refer to the same object if and only if they represent the same type. This allows for comparison of Type objects using reference equality."

Comment: @Sam Harwell - That's not true. I've just been dealing with this issue today. I had 2 System.RuntimeType objects that referred to exactly the same type - same Assembly, Module, GUID, Name, etc. - but Equals returned false. The singleton thing is probably only true for compile-time type objects.

Comment: -1 I am looking at mono implementation and it actually does implement custom == and != so the bolded statement is incorrect. It even overrides Equals() inside PropertyInfo.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you just compare MetadataToken and Module.

According the documentation that combination uniquely identifies.

[MemberInfo.MetadataToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.metadatatoken.aspx)
*A value which, in combination with Module, uniquely identifies a metadata element.*

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.BufferWidth = 200;
    Console.WindowWidth = 140;

    PropertyInfo pi1 = typeof(ClassA).GetProperties()
        .Where(x => x.Name == "ValueA").Single();
    PropertyInfo pi2 = typeof(ClassB).GetProperties()
        .Where(x => x.Name == "ValueA").Single();
    PropertyInfo pi0 = typeof(ClassA).GetProperties()
        .Where(x => x.Name == "ValueB").Single();
    PropertyInfo pi3 = typeof(ClassB).GetProperties()
        .Where(x => x.Name == "ValueB").Single();
    PropertyInfo pi4 = typeof(ClassC).GetProperties()
        .Where(x => x.Name == "ValueA").Single();
    PropertyInfo pi5 = typeof(ClassC).GetProperties()
        .Where(x => x.Name == "ValueB").Single();


    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}", pi1, pi1.ReflectedType, pi1.DeclaringType, pi1.MemberType, pi1.MetadataToken, pi1.Module);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}", pi2, pi2.ReflectedType, pi2.DeclaringType, pi2.MemberType, pi2.MetadataToken, pi2.Module);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}", pi0, pi0.ReflectedType, pi0.DeclaringType, pi0.MemberType, pi0.MetadataToken, pi1.Module);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}", pi3, pi3.ReflectedType, pi3.DeclaringType, pi3.MemberType, pi3.MetadataToken, pi3.Module);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}", pi4, pi4.ReflectedType, pi4.DeclaringType, pi4.MemberType, pi4.MetadataToken, pi4.Module);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}", pi5, pi5.ReflectedType, pi5.DeclaringType, pi5.MemberType, pi5.MetadataToken, pi5.Module);

    // these two comparisons FAIL
    Console.WriteLine("pi1 == pi2: {0}", pi1 == pi2);
    Console.WriteLine("pi1.Equals(pi2): {0}", pi1.Equals(pi2));

    // this comparison passes
    Console.WriteLine("pi1.DeclaringType == pi2.DeclaringType: {0}", pi1.DeclaringType == pi2.DeclaringType);


    pi1 = typeof(ClassA).GetProperties()
        .Where(x => x.Name == "ValueB").Single();

    pi2 = typeof(ClassB).GetProperties()
        .Where(x => x.Name == "ValueB").Single();

    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}", pi1, pi1.ReflectedType, pi1.DeclaringType, pi1.MemberType, pi1.MetadataToken, pi1.Module);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}", pi2, pi2.ReflectedType, pi2.DeclaringType, pi2.MemberType, pi2.MetadataToken, pi2.Module);

    // these two comparisons FAIL
    Console.WriteLine("pi1 == pi2: {0}", pi1 == pi2);
    Console.WriteLine("pi1.Equals(pi2): {0}", pi1.Equals(pi2));


    Console.ReadKey();
}
class ClassA
{
    public int ValueA { get; set; }
    public int ValueB { get; set; }
}
class ClassB : ClassA
{
    public new int ValueB { get; set; } 
}
class ClassC
{
    public int ValueA { get; set; }
    public int ValueB { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I compare `DeclaringType` and `Name`. This reports that the "same" property from two different generic types is different (e.g., `List<int>.Count` and `List<string>.Count`). Comparing `MetadataToken` and `Module` would report that these two properties are the same.

Answer (score 0):

On the outset, it would seem to make sense that two `MemberInfo` are equal if they return the same value when accessing that member directly (not via reflection). For `FieldInfo` this seems more reasonable. However, for `PropertyInfo` it is not so clear because the property could be extended in a subclass, and different `CustomAttributes` could be added to the member declaration. This means that strictly considering the accessed value is insufficient to define equality. However, if that is the definition of equality you want then you may want to consider the `AreEqual3(...)` approach:

```
private class Person {
    [CustomAttribute1]
    public virtual String Name { get; set; }
}

private class Person2 : Person {
    [CustomAttribute2]
    public override String Name { get; set; }
}

public static void TestMemberInfoEquality() {
    MemberInfo m1 = ExpressionEx.GetMemberInfo<Person>(p => p.Name);
    MemberInfo m2 = ExpressionEx.GetMemberInfo<Person2>(p => p.Name);
    bool b1 = m1.MetadataToken == m2.MetadataToken; // false
    bool b2 = m1 == m2; // false (because ReflectedType is different)
    bool b3 = m1.DeclaringType == m2.DeclaringType; // false
    bool b4 = AreEqual1(m1, m2); // false
    bool b5 = AreEqual2(m1, m2); // false
    bool b6 = AreEqual3(m1, m2); // true
}

public static bool AreEqual1(MemberInfo m1, MemberInfo m2) {
    return m1.MetadataToken == m2.MetadataToken && m1.Module == m2.Module;
}

public static bool AreEqual2(MemberInfo m1, MemberInfo m2) {
    return m1.DeclaringType == m2.DeclaringType && m1.Name == m2.Name;
}

public static bool AreEqual3(MemberInfo m1, MemberInfo m2) {
    return m1.GetRootDeclaration() == m2.GetRootDeclaration();
}

public static MemberInfo GetRootDeclaration(this MemberInfo mi) {
    Type ty = mi.ReflectedType;
    while (ty != null) {
        MemberInfo[] arr = ty.GetMember(mi.Name, mi.MemberType, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
        if (arr == null || arr.Length == 0)
            break;
        mi = arr[0];
        ty = ty.BaseType;
    }
    return mi;
}
```

The method has only been written for `Public` and `Instance` members. Some other discussion threads suggest using the `AreEqual1(...)` or `AreEqual2(...)` approaches, but they return `false` for the given example.